# Can a Linux VNC server scale the resolution to the client size?

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer

I have a fairly small resolution (vertically) on my work PC and need to VNC into an Ubuntu desktop. At 1024*768 the window needs to scroll and rolls off the monitor's edge.

With VirtualBox, the guest's screen resolution scales to the size of the Vbox window (with guest additions installed) - is there any way I can get the same behaviour with VNC? I'm using RealVNC VNC Viewer.

Answer (score 3):

Also the **Remmina** "GTK+ Remote Desktop Client" can do client-side scaling.

Comment: You need to do this with the magnifying glass button at the top of your connection window (showing the remote desktop) and not from the initial connection dialog. I haven't seen a way to make it the default for all VNC connections, but it does remember that state the next time you connect.

Answer (score 1):

It's always risky to give a "No." answer to existence questions, because all it takes is a single counter example to completely refute, but let's go: **no**. That is not how explicitly VNC works.

You can however change the resolution with `xrandr` on the remote computer, but it is not *VNC* that would do this. The best a VNC viewer can do is give you a scrollable window.

Another option is to start a separate VNC server for your remote needs. Then you can choose the resolution you want. You can even connect to it locally on the remote machine if you need to do some work there as well. E.g.

```
vncserver -geometry 800x600
```

will start a VNC server *on another display* (e.g. `:1` on port 5901 as compared to the default on `:0`, port 5900) in the background that you can connect to remotely.

More random tips: if you resize the applications to the VNC viewer's window size manually, it will emulate native resolution quite well, I find.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TigerVNC can do this. However, it's a fairly new feature so I'm not sure it has made it into distributions yet.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but x11vnc will allow you to scale the footage before streaming it to you (saving bandwidth and yet still providing the larger resolution to applications).

https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc

Check out the **-scale** option.

Answer (score 0):

If server-side scaling (as opposed to client-side) is important to you (because you want to save bandwitdh aka throughput): LibVNCServer-based servers [support server-side framebuffer scaling](https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver#tackling-low-throughput) if instructed so by a VNC client. A contemporary client which can do this is UltraVNC, there might be others out there as well.

Client-side scaling (with the unscaled,full framebuffer being sent over the network) should be supported in most clients nowadays.